# Regulizer in Conv2D keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I see that people use regulizers in Dense layer but there is a kernel_regulizer argument in Conv2d in keras documentation:

https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/

When I add the regulizers as follows:

```
conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 15), strides=(1, 2), padding='same', data_format='channels_first', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(), input_shape=x_train_n.shape[1:])(g0)
```

I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'regularizers' is not defined
```

I already imported:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, Activation, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization, UpSampling2D, Lambda, \
Conv2DTranspose, Permute, GaussianNoise, advanced_activations, Add, LeakyReLU, Dropout, ActivityRegularization
from tensorflow.python.keras import regularizers

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.figure as fgr
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend
from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import plot_model, normalize
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
```

How can I call regulizers in Conv2D? are there any conflicts in imports?

Comment: Are you sure that you ran the code correctly? That error seems to imply that the line `from tensorflow.python.keras import regularizers` was not run before you attempted to make the conv layer.

Comment: No the error is at the same line of conv2d. Before adding

`from tensorflow.python.keras import regularizers `

 python did not recognize `regularizers.l2()` nor `'l2'`, etc. this was the only way I could pass the argument to conv2D without in line errors from Pycharm IDE.

Comment: Please make a full example that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to run your code without any errors. The only time we received the error was in the scenario @The Guy with The Hat has mentioned, that the line from `tensorflow.python.keras import regularizers` was not run before you attempted to make the `Conv2D` layer.

In the below code, commented the `from tensorflow.python.keras import regularizers`, then we got the error you mentioned.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Input, Activation, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, BatchNormalization, UpSampling2D, Lambda, \
Conv2DTranspose, Permute, GaussianNoise, advanced_activations, Add, LeakyReLU, Dropout, ActivityRegularization
# from tensorflow.python.keras import regularizers

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.figure as fgr
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend
from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 15), strides=(1, 2), padding='same', data_format='channels_first', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(), input_shape=(32,32,3))
```

**Output -**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-2ab79df3a82b> in <module>()
     10 from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
     11 
---> 12 conv1 = Conv2D(32, (3, 15), strides=(1, 2), padding='same', data_format='channels_first', kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(), input_shape=(32,32,3))

NameError: name 'regularizers' is not defined
```

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.